How can I make JSDoc/TypeScript understand JavaScript imports?
I have added // @ts-check to a JavaScript file to use JSDoc. Suddenly I get errors in VS Code for functions included with a script tag:
<script src="imported-file.js"></script>

I can silence these by adding a lot of // @ts-ignore (or maybe other ways?). But that would in my case just make JSDoc/TypeScript a burden.
So instead I wonder what types of ES6 includes/imports JSDoc/TypeScript can handle in VS Code. Can it handle module imports like this one below?
<script type="module" src="imported-file.js"></script>

Can it handle dynamic imports?
const myImportedModule = await import("imported-file.js");

Is there any good documentation about this?

EDIT:
I get the errors when I use the imported functions that are declared in "imported-file.js". They are in the global scope (as seen by JavaScript) just as Jared Smith understood it. The functions are not used in "imported-file.js" and I see no JSDoc errors there.

Your question is unclear. As far as I can tell (and I'm not confident about this) you have a Javascript file that you wrote that relies on certain functions being implicitly in the global scope that you are adding with a script tag that points at Javascript someone else wrote? If that's the case, your options are not great: you can declare a Typescript .d.ts file with signatures for all those functions, or you can tell the compiler to ignore all usage of them (note that disables type checking of those invocations).

There's an exclude option to prevent TS from checking specified files. Still allows importing whatever you like, just makes it shut up about the stuff you don't want to hear about.

@JaredSmith Thanks. Yes, you understood my question correctly. But the "imported-file.js" is also written by me. So I can change it. (However if I need to change it to be a module I have to rethink a lot. It sets up error handling as early as possible.) Is there any other option in this case?

@l3l_aze Thanks. Unfortunately that will not help. See my comment to Jared Smith.

@Leo no that doesn't really change your options. The type checker can only work on stuff that it understands either because you gave it type definitions or because its so simple that the compiler can infer it. There isn't any magic dust to sprinkle here and get type checking without doing the work. You'll have to write declaration (.d.ts) files for the types of your code added by the script tag... or just turn off type checking where they're used via casts or compiler directives. Please do edit the necessary info into the question though, after you do that I'm able to rescind my downvote.

@JaredSmith Thanks again. The type checker says that the functions are not known. Not that they are incorrectly used. The only magic I am asking for is that TypeScript uses what JavaScript knows. JavaScript knows that the function exists. Is there really no way to make this work?

@JaredSmith Obviously there are trouble here. If it should be called a missing feature or a bug seems to be a matter of taste. But I am not sure where it can be solved. Is it the VSCode developers that can do it? Or the TypeScript developers? Or?

No. Nobody can do it, and it's neither a missing feature nor a bug, because it's a logical impossibility: the type checker does not run your HTML. It cannot possibly know about something in a script tag that gets pulled into an HTML page at runtime, because that script tag could point to anything. You know where that file that gets added is, but the compiler does not. So either you have to tell it, or you will need help from an AI that's a lot more Skynet than chatGPT. I'd stick to the former. You can add it in your includes but

...you will still need to add some definitions for those functions. I suggest when you come up against obviously missing features from popular tools that have millions and millions of dollars pumped into them by large companies that you stop and think about what it would take to implement the feature you want in the general case. You will either realize it is extremely difficult/impossible, or you will have a great startup idea.

@JaredSmith Yes, it can be done. It is all about standards and cooperation. The JSDoc checker can ask the compiler.

Gosh, @Leo now that you put it that way all my years of training and experience are clearly wrong. May I suggest that your next project include solving the halting problem? It's just a matter of standards and cooperation right? Or how about a perpetual motion machine? Just need to get the right people in the room.

@JaredSmith I am sorry for that. However I do not train or teach people any longer.

I'm not sure I understand the problem you're describing, but I think what you'll want to do is use the import keyword when defining the type in your JSDocs. For example
// imported-file.js

/**
 * @param {string} x
 * @return {string}
 */
export const identity = x => x

and then where it's imported
// other-file.js
/**
 * @type {import('./imported-file.js').identity}
 */
const id = identity

If that isn't what you're looking for, then I'd need more details about what your specific setup looks like.

Thanks, but export is not allowed in a non-module JavaScript file. So this can't work.

My setup is just plain JavaScript files with JSDoc. As editor I am using VSCode. Nothing else. (TypeScript installed for handling JSDoc.)

This seems like the missing part of the info that will help solve it. This makes it similar to an X Y problem where a user wants X and is using a workaround that creates problem Y which is what they ask about rather than the original problem.

Thanks for your efforts. The solution I found easiest to work with was to just redefine the functions I needed from "imported-file.js". Let say I have a function called myFun in this file. I might then just add a statement like this:
// @ts-ignore
const TSmyFun = myFun;

and then do a simple search and replace. This way I can avoid having a lot of // @ts-ignore for every place where I call myFun.
If you want to add JSDoc and type checking just write a new function TSmyFun.
Tip: I found it very useful to be able to add a comment to ts-ignore:
// @ts-ignore my comment`

